# "would have done" vs "did"

Tags: tense

> They couldn’t go as fast as they **would have liked**, for fear of
>   attracting too much attention.

If I change the "would have liked" to "liked". What's the difference between the meanings?

> They couldn’t go as fast as they **liked**, for fear of attracting too
>   much attention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it's really simple.
As they would have liked means: as they would like in that situation to happen.
On the other hand, as they liked means: the way they wanted that situation to go.

Answer (score 1):

The first means that there is some speed that they wanted to go in that particular situation. The second means there is some speed that they generally prefer.

Answer (score -1):

With the past subjective for the comparison, the alternative is a hypothetical (not real) situation:

- They couldn't do as much as they would have done [under some condtion].

With the simple past for the comparison, the alternative is some real situation previous to the one under discussion:

- They couldn't do as much as they did [at some other time].

There are two things that make your specific example of "like" tricky:

"To like" is not an action verb, so the exact moment that they formed the preference to go a particular speed doesn't change the meaning that much:

- They couldn't go as far as they expected to.  *Expectation was formed before the going.  The result was unexpected, but only compared to the previous expectation.*
- They couldn't go as far as they would have expected.  *If they had thought about it beforehand, they would have expected to go farther, but they didn't think about it in advance.*

The other thing that makes this tricky is that "as *X* as you like/want/please" is an idiomatic expression meaning that the amount of *X* is not limited by someone/something else.  "You can drive as fast as you like" does literally mean what it says, but the implication is that nothing is limiting your speed:

- They couldn't go as fast as they planned. *They made the plan before going, and something prevented them from following the plan, like "attracting too much attention".*
- They couldn't go as fast as they liked. *They had to obey some constraint that made them go slower. Doesn't sound like they actually formed some preference in advance because of the idiomatic meaning.*

Your second example sounds like, "They couldn't go fast for fear of attracting too much attention."  It doesn't actually sound like a comment on their preference like the first sentence does.